# PHP MongoDB\..\ServerException Failed to send "getMore" command with database "Model": socket error or timeout

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor

Can somebody help me to fix this PHP MongoDB exception:

> Failed to send "getMore" command with database "Model": socket error or timeout

It comes from query to big collection (14mils). The query looks like:

```
$options = [
            'noCursorTimeout' => true,
            'batchSize' => 50,
            'projection' => ['dateFrom' => 1, 'dateTo' => 1, 'ico' => 1, 'city' => 1, 'address' => 1, 'name' => 1, 'type' => 1]
        ];

$docs = $this->mapper->getCollection()->find([
            '$or' => [
                ['dateFrom' => ['$lte' => $bsonTo], 'dateTo' => NULL],
                ['dateFrom' => ['$lt' => $bsonFrom], 'dateTo' => ['$gte' => $bsonFrom]],
                ['dateFrom' => ['$gte' => $bsonFrom, '$lte' => $bsonTo]]
            ]
        ], $options);
```

I set noCursorTimemout + batchSize cause at first I get Cursor not found exception. But now I have this. Thanks.